# print pdf with selected printer from dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Hi all i am trying to print a pdf file. For this i have created a windows form application. My application print the pdf if i use the default printer of the system. But problem is that when i try to print the PDF file with selected printer from dropdown my code does not works.

```
 private bool SendToPrinter(string filePath, string filename)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        string PrinterName;
        string PaperName;
        PrinterName = "";
        try
        {
            PrinterName = Convert.ToString(cmbPrinterList.SelectedItem);
            // Set the printer.
             AddPrinterConnection(PrinterName);
             SetDefaultPrinter(PrinterName);
            //Print the file with number of copies sent.
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Verb = "print";
            info.Arguments = "\"" + PrinterName + "\"";
            info.FileName = @filePath + @"\" + filename;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.UseShellExecute = true;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForInputIdle();                
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
            if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
                p.Kill();
            Status = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Status;
    }

    //Set the added printer as default printer.
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);

   //Add the printer connection for specified pName.
   [DllImport("winspool.drv")]
    public static extern bool AddPrinterConnection(string pName);
    public bool viewTabOrder = true;
```

Comment: kindly state your error. what do you mean by your code does not work.

Comment: @active92 I want to say that my code does not print the pdf file with my selected Printer

Comment: @active92 but work with default printer of the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code
This is working with different printers for me. Hope it will help you too :)

```
public void SendToPrinter(string filePath, string Printer)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.Refresh();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReaderPath"].ToString();                    
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", filePath, Printer);
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.Start();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                if (proc.HasExited == false)
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit(20000);
                }
                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                proc.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Code to bind the Printers into dropdownlist.

```
cmbPrinter.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Printer--");

for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
{
     var pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
     cmbPrinter.Items.Insert(i + 1, pkInstalledPrinters);
}
```

And Pass the parameter as below

```
SendToPrinter(FilePath,cmbPrinter.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks for answer but this is sending copy to print for default printer :(

Comment: Have you tried to pass printer name into Printer parameter of this method?

Comment: Then I believe problem is in the dropdown binding of printernames
let me add the code to bind the printer dropdown and pass the selected printer name to this method.

Comment: Thanks i will check it today and let you know

Comment: again not work for me it is sending to print my default printer for testing i hard code  `PrinterName = @"\\server1\HP DeskJet 5820 series";`  but it is sending to `\\pc22\HP LaserJet 1020` that is my default printer. Can you please advice me

Comment: are you getting both the printer names in dropdownlist ?

Comment: yes i am getting all the printer name in my dropdownlist . That dropdown i bind with the code you provide me

Comment: so you must be passing the printer name with `cmbPrinter.SelectedItem.ToString();` right?
I think are you able to print any document with the different printer?
Otherwise try to remove default  printer from the control panel.

you can also test the same application to some others machine to know the problem better.

Comment: Thanks i going to test and let you know

Comment: i have test and now its working fine Thanks again i have upvote your answer.